# WCF Service Authorizing with Active Directory - Access Denied Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-security

I have a question around WCF authorization against a domain account over HTTP traffic hosted on IIS (none production so no ssl cert was available to use over the internet)

I'd like to know how to set up windows authentication from a client to my web service. currently I'm testing on the same LAN so proxies are not a problem

I have included a list of tried steps at the end of this post

**Edit:** The error that is occurring is just Access is denied, nothing else, given from the
try, catch in the Client Application. If there is a way to get more detailed information, please let me know and ill add the result to the post.

WCF Service code:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]  

ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]    

public class Data : IData
    {
        [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role=@"Administrators")]

        public List<Incident> GetCases()
        {            

            Queries query = new Queries();

            List<Incident> iList = query.CallCases();

            return iList;

         }
   }
```

WCF Web Config Bindings:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
        <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

WCF Web Config Behavior:

```
<behavior name="Behaviour1">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
            <add scheme="http" port="9577" /> ///This port is correct
        </defaultPorts>
    </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
</behavior>
```

WCF Web Config Service:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Behaviour1" name="WebService1.Data">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="WebService1.IData">
         <identity>
              <dns value="demo.DomainName.co.uk" />
         </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Client Application (Has Service reference added)

```
            DataClient client = new DataClient();

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
        PrincipalPermission principalPerm = new PrincipalPermission(null, "Administrators");
        principalPerm.Demand();
        Console.WriteLine("Demand succeeded.");

        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "Domain Name";
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "User Account";
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";

        //client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"UserAccount@domain.com";
        //client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
        //client.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;

        try
        {
            List<Incident> cases = client.GetCases().ToList();

            foreach (Incident Inc in cases)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Inc.CaseID);
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Attempted Resolutions:

- Using Domain and Local Users
- Modifying the Client Credential type to basic, NTLM and Windows
- using setting IIS to use
- IIS has Basic and Windows Authentication Enabled

if you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You've written a good question for a first time poster, but I think one small but important piece of information is missing - namely, what is the behavior or errors you're seeing?  Also, I think setting `securityMode` to "None" might be impacting what you're trying to do - the child security settings may be ignored (that's just a guess on my part).

Comment: Thanks Tim, completely forgot to add that, I have added it in now. And thank you for the warm welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tim pointed me in the right direction, this was the resolution:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="TransportSecurity">
    <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
    </security>
</binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Because I have no SSL Certificate I needed to set the security mode to Message, I was getting confused as most people test using SSL, which would require transport security as well I had set it to None for testing.

Thanks for the help Tim